# content maching preview of giphy bot in discord

Tags: discord.js

I'm building a bot in discord and i would like to add a slash command feature that will allow the user to select a choice from many (like a drop down menu). However, you can't add more than 25 choices for a slash command option. So my alternative solution is to have a content matching preview like with giphy bot when the user type a string i will update the content accordingly.
However, i don't find any guide on how i can implement this behavior. is it about updating choices on interactionCreate event?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way the bot is doing that is through something called Autocomplete. Basically, you can declare a command to have Autocomplete and then, in the `interactionCreate` event listener, you can check if the command is an Autocomplete interaction, then respond with something. You can set the command to be Autocomplete by using this in one of the options for the command:

```js
.setAutocomplete(true)
```

Then, in your main file, where you have the `interactionCreate` event listener, you can just check when a command is an Autocomplete interaction by using `interaction.isAutocomplete()`. Then, you can respond to the interaction by using this:

```js
const value = interaction.options.getFocused() // This gets the value which the user typed
const response = await interaction.respond({
    name: '', // The name of the response
    value: '' // The value of the response
})
```

You can learn more about Autocomplete here => [Autocomplete | discord.js](https://discordjs.guide/interactions/autocomplete.html#enabling-autocomplete)

However, I'm not sure if any bot can do that since this was hard coded to be like that by Discord and since bots can only respond with strings (I think).